# ES6 String Interpolation in Aurelia

Tags: ecmascript-6, aurelia

I am trying to follow the "Getting Started" section on aurelia.io and having some problem with string interpolation inside a string.

In the viewmodel in the first example, the 'fullName' calculated getter returns a string

```
return '${this.firstName} ${this.lastName}'
```

This value is used in the view (html template) as ${fullName}.

The problem is instead of showing the calculated full name, the actual return string is shown.  I have tried with both Chrome and Firefox and both are not showing the correct value.

Same problem exists with the welcome() function since it also returns a string value.

I noticed in the Aurelia Visual Studio sample, the return values were changed to the actual calculated string.

```
return this.firstName + " " + this.lastName;
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Your answer is correct. This is actually a feature of ECMAScript 6, not Aurelia specifically. In ES6, the ` character, not the ' character, delimits templated strings.

Regarding the Visual Studio sample, this is just another style of outputting the same result. This style, however, is valid in ECMAScript 5/JavaScript. You could also write the following, as they are all equivalent:

```
return [this.firstName, this.lastName].join(' ');
```

Comment: Thank you for the clarification.  Just starting to learn ES6 and made the mistake.  On Visual Studio, version 1.4 of Typescript now supports string interpolation so the same format can be used directly.

Comment: It does, however I've had some trouble getting it to work, just FYI. Also, if this answer was helpful, please upvote and accept. :)

Comment: Is the problem with Typescript random?

Comment: no, I have never been able to get string templating to work in ttypescript

Answer (score 5):

My novice mistake.  I used a single quote rather than a back stroke for the string interpolation string.

So the proper way is

```
return `${this.firstName} ${this.lastName}`
```

Sorry about that.